# Multidevice layout SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this layout working fine in iPhone 11, but when I switch to 8, the top background color gets disproportionate, how can I make it have the same height? Is there such a thing as height %?

[image]

and the one that gets weird:

[image]

This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}


struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SetBackground()
            Text("Home View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

struct ArcShape : Shape {
    let geometry: GeometryProxy
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        let center = CGPoint(x: 290, y: 100)
        p.addArc(center: center, radius:  geometry.size.width * 3, startAngle: .degrees(39), endAngle: .degrees(140), clockwise: false)
        return p
    }
}

struct SetBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Color.white
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    ArcShape(geometry: geometry)
                        .offset(x:  geometry.size.width * -0.3, y:  geometry.size.height * -1.49)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)

                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

The rest is working fine, it's just that top background that shifts if the iPhone model changes. I tried putting it in a frame but that just gets it weird on the middle :/

Also, why does it changes if I put the tabView and only leave HomeView()? It's so weird

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to hardcoded Arc center & different safe-areas on different devices.

So the solution is to make Arc position geometry dependent (specific factors you can fit)

[image: demo1][image: demo2]

```
struct ArcShape : Shape {
    let geometry: GeometryProxy
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        let center = CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: -geometry.size.height * 1.75) // 1/4 from top
        p.addArc(center: center, radius:  geometry.size.height * 2, startAngle: .degrees(39), endAngle: .degrees(140), clockwise: false)
        return p
    }
}

struct SetBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Color.white
                    ArcShape(geometry: geometry)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)

                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to start calling you the super man of the code. Thank again, I hope some day to have half of your knowledge in Swift